# Issue With Deploy Services Under Custom API Domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

I was following the Serverless blog post: https://serverless.com/blog/api-gateway-multiple-services using it as a guide in my attempt to deploy services under a custom domain. However, I am receiving the following error:

An error occurred: pathmapping - Only one base path mapping is allowed if the base path is empty.

The relevant entry in the serverless.yml is:

```
custom:
  stage: ${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}
  domains:
    prod: prod-api.admin.acme.org
    qa: qa-api.admin.acme.org
    dev: api-dev.admin.acme.org

customDomain:
  basePath: “people”
  domainName: {self:custom.domains.{self:custom.stage}}
  stage: “${self:custom.stage}”
  createRoute53Record: true

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-2
  profile: acme-api
  environment: {file(env.yml):{self:provider.stage}}

functions:
  listUsers:
    handler: list_items.list
    events:
      - http:
        path: users
        method: get
        cors: true
```

Anything sticks out that I screw up on?

Thanks for looking …